# Is Inducing Limits in Irrationality proof valid?

Tags: limits, irrational-numbers

first of all, I want to say that I am pretty new to math. So, if there are any mistake, please told me.

I attempt to proof that $e^{e}$ is irrational.

$e^{e} = e^{1}*e^{1}*e^{1/2!}*e^{1/3!}*...$

Suppose an integer "a" We can rewritten equation as

$e^{e} = e^{1}*e^{1}*e^{1/2!}*e^{1/3!}*...*e^{1/a!}*e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a+n)!}}$

$(e^{e})^{a!} = (e^{1}*e^{1}*e^{1/2!}*e^{1/3!}*...*e^{1/a!})^{a!}*(e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a!}{(a+n)!}})$

Induce the Limit, We got

$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} {(e^{e})^{a!}} = \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}(e^{1}*e^{1}*e^{1/2!}*e^{1/3!}*...*e^{1/a!})^{a!}*(e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a!}{(a+n)!}})$

We can derive that

$(e^{e})^{integer} = e^{integer}*(e^0)$

There was a proof already that $e^{integer}$ and this also imply that $e^{e}$ is irrational because, irrational only come irrational * irrational.

But still, I'm not sure that could we use limit in this kind of proof. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You need to put TeX notation between dollar signs.

Comment: Edited already. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, I can hardly blame you for being confused by that step. As you've reproduced it here, it makes no sense at all. You have *not* derived that $(e^e)^\text{integer} = e^\text{integer}\cdot e^0$. (Also $e^0 = 1$, which is quite rational. And also, irrational $\times$ irrational can be rational.) But I suspect you have misinterpreted the proof and what you've written here is your misinterpretation, not the actual proof offered. Can you link to the source, or else reproduce it faithfully here? Then we can provide you useful guidance.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question of whether $e^e$ is irrational is still open. Maybe recent research has settled it, though.

Comment: Irrationality proofs are much harder than many people probably think. In fact, $e^e$ belongs to the unknown cases.